# Count occurrences of a string in comments

Tags: excel, vba

I just started trying some VBA in excel, and I'm trying to count how many occurrences of a certain word there are in the comments of a selection. Here's what I have so far :

```
Function CountStringInComments(strText As String, ByVal Target As Range) As Long

Dim c As Comment
Dim n As Long

For Each c In Target.Comments
n = n - (InStr(1, c.Text, strText, vbTextCompare) > 0)
Next

CountStringInComments = n
Set c = Nothing
End Function
```

and calling my function should look like :

```
=CountStringInComments("bruit",Z55:Z58)
```

I get a #VALUE! error.

I'm not familiar with VB so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide clarification. When you say in Comments, is this in 1 cell in Excel or in a list of cells? 

Or

Is this actual comments in the VBA code?

Comment: I'm looking in a list of  cells in excel (not in the VBA code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to itrate the cells not the comments and then search the comments text of that cell.

```
Function CountStringInComments(strText As String, ByVal Target As Range) As Long

Dim c As Range
Dim n As Long

For Each c In Target.Cells
    If Not c.Comment Is Nothing Then
        n = n - (InStr(1, c.Comment.Text, strText, vbTextCompare) > 0)
    End If
Next

CountStringInComments = n
Set c = Nothing
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and I seem to be getting the same error.

Comment: @FrançoisChampagne it is working for me,  The cell shows the contents of the comments.

Comment: I was able to make it work in another worksheet, now I just need to figure out why it won't work in the other one. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @FrançoisChampagne make sure the code is in a module not the sheet code.

Comment: I figured what my problem was : the code doesn't work if a cell does not have a comment (probably because of InStr). Obviously some of the cells won't have a comment. Do you have an idea of a condition I could add.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to count all matches(including multiple times in a single comment), then you could do like:

```
Function CountStringInComments(str As String, ByVal r As Range) As Long

    Dim re As RegExp
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = str
    re.IgnoreCase = True

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In r
        If Not cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            Dim mColl As MatchCollection
            Set mColl = re.Execute(cell.Comment.Text)
            CountStringInComments = CountStringInComments + mColl.Count
        End If
    Next cell

End Function
```

Needs to reference *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5*